# Database design queries regarding inheritance and foreign key references

Tags: sql, database-design, inheritance, foreign-keys

I have  a query regarding a design problem that I faced …

There is  a table A with subtypes B and C. Table A has an attribute type which tells whether the type is B or C. The common attributes of B and C are in A .

The problem is that there are no extra attributes for B .. all attributes required  for B are in A already. However , there are extra attributes for C.

Is it an acceptable solution if I make tables A and C only ??… to extract entities of B I will query through the type attribute from table A

Can you refer any material  ?

I also had a another confusion where table A has subtypes B,C,D . Table Z  has a column that requires a value of primary id of  either B or C but NOT D.

I thought of adding the primary id column of A as a foreign key reference to Z’s column and then making a trigger to ensure that the id isn't D ...

Can anyone please comment ?

Thank you !

Comment: You should split this in to two separate questions, one for each paragraph, in order to keep everything clear and straightforward. Regarding the first part: if there's really no need to store any additional information for B types, then there's no need for a B table. For the second, you should make a check constraint on the Z table's column to prevent invalid values from being inserted. Don't use a trigger. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187550.aspx#Check

Answer (score 2):

Many people just enforce all these rules in application code.  That is, they "simply" don't insert wrong data.  Of course this is very fragile and depends on writing perfect application code at all times.  So we want the database to enforce the constraints instead, so that wrong data can never be inserted.

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  type CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  unique key (id, type)
);

CREATE TABLE B (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  type CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'B',
  FOREIGN KEY (id, type) REFERENCES A(id, type)
);
```

If you can force B.type to always be 'B' (CHECK constraint, trigger, or reference a one-row lookup table) then it can of course reference parent rows in A where type='B'.  And do something similar in tables C and D, so then each row of A can be referenced by a row from only one sub-type table.

That is, if A.type is 'B' on a given row, and C.type can only be 'C', then no row of C can reference any row where A.type is 'B'.

Now if you want table Z to reference B or C but not D, you can reference by id *and* type, so Z also has its own type column.  You can restrict Z.type by using a lookup table:

```
CREATE TABLE Ztypes (
  type CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO Ztypes VALUES ('B'), ('C');

CREATE TABLE Z (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Aid INT NOT NULL,
  type CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (Aid, type) REFERENCES A(id, type),
  FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES Ztypes(type)
);
```

Comment: Thankyou for the response ! i am still confused about the first part .. Should i make a separate table for B? My question was that A has attributes aid ,a1 , a2 , a3 . C and B are A's subtypes. When i make a table for C it has attributes cid , c1 , c2 .. while for B i have no attributes other than the bid! won't it be weird to create a table with no other attributes ?? or is there any other solution ??

Comment: You don't need to create a table for B, if A already notes the type.  If anyone asks, you can say you *do* have a table for B, but it's hard to see because it has zero columns.  :-)

Comment: And if you ever discover you do need B-specific attributes in the future, you can create a table for B at that time and populate it with all id's from A where type='B'.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got the answer you were looking for.  But for other who run across this, it's worth researching two techniques:  Class Table Inheritance and Shared Primary Key.

These two techniques used together make it fast, simple and easy to join A's data with either B's or C's data.  And in this pattern, B contains only the key, but still contains usefull informaton.

Both of these techiques have their own tags.